# $interval refreshing directives

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

Please take a look at this code: ([on plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/rsKZBDCY2ACK1XcEt0EU))

```
angular
    .module('intervalExample', [])
    .controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', '$interval', function($scope, $interval) {
            $interval(function() {
                //nothing..
            }, 1000);

            $scope.do = function() {
                console.log(new Date());
                return true;
            }
    }]);

<body ng-app="intervalExample">
    <div>
        <div ng-controller="ExampleController">
            <div ng-if="do()">text</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

If you open the console you'll see that `$scope.do` is being called every second. Why is that? why is `$interval` causing the directive to reload? Is there a way to avoid it?
It happens with other directives (such as ngShow) as well..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the entire point of how Angular works. Every time the handler registered via `$interval` fires, Angular does a digest cycle, which means it checks every watch expression to see if anything has changed. If a change is detected, Angular will modify the DOM to reflect the change. Because `do()` is called by a watch expression registered by `ng-if`, it is also called every time the timer fires.

If you don't want this, don't use `$interval`; just use a normal `setInterval` call, but note that any data you modify within the callback will not cause your Angular templates to be updated. This approach is not recommended. Rather, if the problem with calling `do()` every second is that `do()` is too expensive, find a way to make it cheaper, such as by caching the result.

Comment: Thanks that's a very good explanation. Also, I found I can pass `false` on the 4th argument (invokeApply) so it skips the dirty checking.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I think this is because `$interval` causes digest pass and ng-if gets tested every time this happens, so your $scope.do() gets evaluated every time.

I don't think passing in a callable there is a good idea in general.